# filter search react js

Tags: reactjs, search, filter, searchbar

Why I m getting this error 1. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
2. TypeError: getData.filter is not a function.

````
function Search(props) {
      const {getData}= props;
       const [searchTerm,setSearchTerm] = useState('')
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <input type="text" placeholder="seach..." onChange={e=>setSearchTerm(e.target.value)} />
          {getData.filter((item)=>{
              if(searchTerm === ""){
                  return item
                }
                else if(item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
                    return item;
                  }
                  return item;
                }).map((item,key)=>{
                    return <div>{item.title} </div>
                  })}
                </div>
              );
            }
            
          export default Search; ```
````

Comment: what is `getData`?

Comment: getData().filter?

Comment: You need to return an array from your getData or convert it to an array